# how to create category with SQLITE in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, xcode4

i have a sqlite database like this :

table1:

```
categoryID     name   description
    1            a         dog
    1            b          cat
    2            c          elephant
    2            d        bird
```

table2:

```
categoryID      categoryName
    1               ex1
    2                ex2
    3               ex4
```

how to want to create category in first view with categoryID and categoryName ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a join? Some like: SELECT Table1.name, Table2.CategoryName FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.categoryId = Table2.categoryId AND Table1.categoryId = 1;

Comment: and how much i shoud define a sample query ? 1 more for define category 1 more for define cell 1 more for define description ??

can i define all request in one query ??

Comment: First, you should always keep in mind, thta joins are expensive in consumption. As a rule of thumb you can remember, that a join across five tables will usually kill your applikation. so, simply put: the less, the better. You might want to take a look at normalizing tables, that explaain, which data goes into what table generally, to avoid redundancy. HTH. BTW. PLease accept the answer ;)